# VSCode First Extension Hello World Example --inspect Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

About 10 months ago I started writing my own extension for VSCode I set everything up following the page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world
Everything was running/debugging fine. Few days ago I went back to it and after software updates all I get is a Ensure Node was launched with --inspect... ... Error,

I can't even run the Hellow World example.  Can anyone help me?

this is the launch.json file it gave me

```js
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js" ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}", "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/out/test" ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/out/test/**/*.js" ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have since had  to ditch this editor Because I am left with the impression that if you do not already know how to use this product then you shouldn't be using it. Yet another third rate product from Microsoft.